# Pop-up/Drop-down menu in jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, drop-down-menu

I'm supposed to do following thing:

There's a button, after clicking on/touching it there should be pop-up menu, or better, drop-down menu, with list (listview!) of available options.

Is it even possible with JQM? I know there are dialog boxes, but these look like new page, and we don't like it.

I tried using some pre-made jQuery drop-downs, but none of them supports touch, mostly mouse-over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what you want exactly, but it seems like you could do something like [that](http://jsfiddle.net/pektB/)
to have a menu using listview.

If you want to add a nice hide/show transition, I suggest looking at the [CSS3 Transition](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transition.asp)

Comment: Near, but not this. I want menu items to be in pop-up. Like here: http://www.webdesigndev.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/fancydropdown.html with 2 differences, 1. menu is vertical, 2. ontouch event not mousover.

Comment: Even better if this was dialog like here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#animated but this one doesn't seem to work properly, even if I take code as is without any changes.

Comment: Well this should be a basis, you can change it as wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/pektB/3/ (note that it uses a "vclick" event for now, but you can change to "ontouch" if needed)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's something I needed ;D